# MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm encountering a MongoDB duplicate key error when trying to register a new user in my Node.js and Express application. The error message is:

```
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: "" }
```

Here is my user schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = require('mongoose');

const user_schema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    password: String
});

const User_Model = mongoose.model('User', user_schema);
module.exports = User_Model;
```

And here is my registration endpoint in index.js:

```
app.post('/register', async(req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
    const userProfile = await User.create({
        name,
        email,
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, hashyPassword)
    });
    res.json(userProfile);
});
```

I'm using bcrypt for password hashing. It seems like the unique: true constraint on the email field is causing the issue. What could be the reason behind this error, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: You set in your schema email to `unique=true`, A document with the same value of the email field already exists.

Comment: If you `console.log('req.body: ', req.body);` as the first statement in your  `app.post('/register` route handler what does it print?

Answer (score 0):

From the error you are getting

You would need to check a few things.

1. Ensure that the email is not empty; this can be a validation check
2. Check if the email exists before creating it.

For a drop-in solution to your question:

```js
app.post('/register', async(req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    const userExists = await User.find({ email: email.trim() })
    if (userExists) return res.json({ error: true, message: "Email already exists" })


    const userProfile = await User.create({
        name,
        email,
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, hashyPassword)
    });
    res.json(userProfile);
});
```